# Copy-Item Moving Items to another location without creating a parent directory

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

If I want to move the following structure

```
Parent
  ChildParent
    ChildOfAChildParent
```

to the following Location:

```
NewParent
  NewChildParent <-- here
```

I get the following when running the following

```
Copy-Item "\Parent\ChildParent\ChildOfAChildParent" -Destination "NewParent\NewChildParent" -Recurse

NewParent
  NewChildParent
    ChildOfAChildParent
```

This is not the behavior I want and I am not sure how to achieve. I just want to dump the files and folders from ChildOfAChildParent into NewChildParent without creating a new parent directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this (Fewf) by adding a `\*` to my from path, so it would actually be:

```
Copy-Item "\Parent\ChildParent\ChildOfAChildParent\*" -Destination "NewParent\NewChildParent" -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

You're telling the OS to move folder "C" from "A\B\C" into "A\B". Even if you did this under a GUI with right-mouse clicks the result would be the same. C would become nested under B.

What you actually want to do is copy A\B\C\D into A\B. So the command that Nerd in Training gave you above is doing that. Because you're basically turning 1 file copy operation into x, where x is the number of files matching "*" in A\B\C.

So to visualise this, it becomes:

Copy A\B\C\d.1    A\B\d.1
Copy A\B\C\d.2    A\B\d.2
Copy A\B\C\d.3    A\B\d.3

Answer (score -1):

i would use the move-item variable instead of copy-item. This would do what it is you are looking for by moving the item you designate from your selected path after the move-item function into the current active directory.